# How to get money back from tax filing in US?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax

I'm on a student visa in the MA, US. This year(2019) it was my first time filing for tax as I got the part-time job on-campus in my university. I submitted the tax form to a person who came to my university on April's end. He didn't charge me for the process. But, it's been more than a month and I haven't received the money which I was expected to get from tax return. Also, that person is not responding to my emails and phone calls. I don't owe any money to the government instead, I'm expected to receive money after I file the tax. Is there any way I can get that money at this time? Or is it too late? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does [Where's my refund?](https://www.irs.gov/refunds) page say?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm new to this, so I'm a complete noob in this. Do I need to enter just "Federal income tax withheld" in refund amount or total of state and federal tax?

Comment: Neither - you enter the federal refund amount that you expect.

Comment: Thanks! It says 'You may not have entered your information correctly. Please verify your personal tax data and try again.' I've entered details correctly I'm sure.

Comment: who is "a person who came to my university on April's end"? was this a service the university offered? what paperwork did they leave with you?

Comment: You say *I'm on a student...* - did you mean *I'm a student* or *I'm on a student visa* (or something else)?

Comment: Do you have a copy of your tax return?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep this person was providing volunteer tax filing services for international students, who was not a university employee.

Comment: @yoozer8 I'm on a student visa. I'm sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: @HartCO Yes, I have a copy of my tax return

Comment: Did this person say they were _filing_ your return and not simply _preparing_ it? If they filed _electronically_ (aka e-file, and _if_ 'volunteer' means VITA = a specific IRS program Volunteer Income Tax Assistance, they are supposed to use e-file whenever possible) did you get an e-file receipt, which might be labelled 'electronic postmark'?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 He was from VITA program. He asked me to fill out a single large page form and took my half portion of the taxes document which states state and federal taxes. I didn't receive any e-file receipt as you mentioned. Please help me.

Comment: That's odder. If you mean they _took_ (not just looked at and gave back) your W-2(s), that would be consistent with paper filing, which a paid preparer might do, but my understanding of the VITA/TCE rules is that if they don't efile they should give _you_ the prepared, signed paper return (with W-2 stapled to it for Federal, and usually state also) for _you_ to mail. But there might be an exception I don't know about -- or a mistake. I don't think I/we can help more over the Internet if you aren't able to contact the person or the local organization sponsoring them (apparently your school).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You definitely need to find out what 'that person' ever did or didn't do. Nobody here can tell you that.

- Maybe he never filed your taxes
- Maybe he didn't file your taxes yet because he was too busy
- Maybe he is a scammer and took your refund and left
- Maybe he filed and mistyped your SSN / ITIN, or the amount.
- Maybe he filed late and the processing hasn't yet started ("where's my refund" only works about a week after successfully filing)

Comment: Ultimately if the OP can't get ahold of this person, and the automated "where's my refund?" tool isn't helping, the next step seems to be contacting the IRS via phone or in writing.

Comment: I checked on "where's my refund" and it gives me the message "You may not have entered your information correctly. Please verify your personal tax data and try again." In what scenarios I would get this message?

Comment: When you mistyped it, when the filer mistyped it, or when it was never filed. You can only use that to check for really filed taxes